# Why does equipping a 2 handed bow instead of a 1-handed shows wrong change in damage?

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-demon-hunter

I equipped my DH with a 1-handed bows, then I wanted to equip a stronger 2-handed bow. When I hovered over the bow the game showed a -56.1 change in damage if equipped, however when I equipped it, my damage went from 439.4 to 452.77, so it's obvious that the "hover over tool tip" was wrong.

What is the source for this preference of 1-handed weapons over 2-handed?

When the 1-handed bow is equipped:

[image]
When the 2-handed bow is equipped:

[image]
The set of skills (active & passive) that are chosen:

[image]
Stats for the quiver:

[image]

Comment: Perhaps it is not accounting for the gem properly.

Comment: What are the stats of your off-hand weapon in the DW scenario?  Also, what is your crit% and crit dmg%?

Comment: Please include a screenshot of the passives you're using, and stat information like attack speed, critical hit damage and critical hit chance, as this effects the damage calculation as well - the Archery passive for example gives increased critical damage % when using a crossbow in comparison to additional attack speed % when using hand crossbows.

Comment: Later today I'll update this question with a more detailed case that happened to me...

Comment: I hope that this new case gives all the needed information to get the answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're wielding a one-hander and an off-handed item, the DPS comparison with a two-hander assumes you'll be un-equipping both weapon slots, which is perfectly valid in all cases... except with demon hunters and quivers. In that case, the calculation is off by an amount equal to the extra DPS your quiver gives you.

In fact, the game used to automatically unequip your quiver for you when swapping a 1h crossbow with a 2h weapon. I don't know if it still does this, but it's something to watch out for.

Comment: Tip: Temporarily unequip the quiver while you compare 1h and 2h bows.

Comment: +1 this is the correct answer, if you unequip the quiver the tooltip will show the correct numbers. I do believe it happens the same with comparing two 2h bows/xbows when having a quiver equipped.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that the hovering-over info didn't calculate that extra `Dexterity` that you get from the bow.

Or it might be exactly what [*Catalept*](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/22645/catalept) said in his [answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/79898/25490). Try taking off the quiver when you use a bow and see if the `DPS` will be around *383.3*. If so, then he was right and the game does unequip the quiver with 2H (cross)bows.

Answer (score -1):

This is probably because the tooltip does not account for the 15 % attack speed increase you get for dual wielding. More attack speed equals more DPS.

Also, you normally alternate attacks between two weapons when dual wielding, so the damage from one weapon does not necessarily directly translate into the total DPS count.

Comment: In this particular case though, the DPS figures are showing as higher for the two handed weapon, which doesn't add additional attack speed

Comment: The total DPS displayed (The one on the Attributes section) is displaying normally. It is the tool tip that is screwing up, due to what I think is not including the 15 % Atk Speed increase for Dual Wield.

Comment: On further study I think I just got crosseyed, so lemme get back to you on that one...

Comment: Quivers don't count as dual-wielding.

Answer (score -2):

This is because the game assumes that only the main hand weapon will change. This means it assumes that you will have 1 2H crossbow and 1 1H crossbow instead of 2 1H crossbows equipped, which you cannot do.

The algorithm for the calculation is not good enough to understand that you need to change other gear too. You have the same problems with quivers and shields if you change your weapons to sword or crossbow.

If you want to evaluate your alternatives just equip 1 2H crossbow + quiver and compare the DPS to 2 1H crossbow.

Comment: this is not the case, if what you say is true, then it should show higher increase in damage than the real increase, but it show a decrease instead of an increase.